# test artisan command laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I'm trying to write a test command in Laravel 9. In the below code the new user will create successfully **But** after creating need to redirect the Dashboard page

```
public function test_an_action_that_requires_authentication()
{
    $user = $this->artisan('make:user',[
        'name' => "username",
        'email' => "useremail",
        'password' => Str::random(8)
    ]);
}
```

How to redirect to the route after success created

Comment: I did not understand your question: you need to test IF after the creation your code will redirect? Or you need to develop the redirect?

Comment: Hi Giacomo M Thank you for your reply. To access Routes need to success auth. That means must create new users before redirecting the Dashboard page. How can redirect after success create user

Comment: The redirect will come in the original controller, and doesn't happen in an artisan command. Redirects are only for web routes.

Comment: I'm create a custom command

Answer (score 0):

We will use the `assertExitCode` method to assert that the command completed with a given exit code.

```php
$this->artisan('module:import')
    ->expectsConfirmation('Do you really wish to run this command?', 'no')
    ->assertExitCode(1);
```

for more information you can find here

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/console-tests

Answer (score -2):

N.B. This code does not work in test. You can not redirect in an artisan command.

Said that, in laravel, to redirect to the home page, you can use this code in a controller function:

```
return redirect(url('/'));
```